# Como tratar de maneira encapsulada um campo que é uma lista de elementos imutáveis?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lista

Imagine que você tem um objeto e um de seus campos é uma lista de elementos imutáveis.

Você quer disponibilizar esse campo para os clientes desse objeto de forma controlada, afinal uma lista pode ser alterada e receber ou perder elementos, invalidando o objeto e violando o princípio do encapsulamento.

O que disponibilizar para o cliente? Depende da regra de negócio, você vai responder. Mas considere de forma geral algumas opções.

Uma das opções é disponibilizar um método getter que acesse uma cópia da lista. Dessa forma, tendo os elementos já imutáveis, a lista original fica também imutável.

Outra opção é disponibilizar um getter que acessa os elementos um a um: `getElement(int posicao)`.

Outra opção é disponibilizar um iterator.

A pergunta é, essa última opção faz sentido? Eu costumo incluí-la entre as opções possíveis mas acabo desistindo, achando que o design não fica bom. Mas volta e meia penso nela. Por isso esta pergunta. O que acham?

Comment: Relacionado: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/EncapsulatedCollection.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sob o ponto de vista do encapsulamento, normalmente considero que a melhor abordagem é a seguinte:

```
public class SuaClasse {

    // Embora AlgumaCoisa seja imutável, a lista em si é mutável.
    private List<AlgumaCoisa> algumaLista;

    public SuaClasse() {
        // ...
    }

    public List<AlgumaCoisa> getAlgumaLista() {
        return List.copyOf(algumaLista);
    }

    public void adicionarItem(AlgumaCoisa adicionando) {
        this.algumaLista.add(adicionando);
    }
}
```

O método [`List.copyOf(Collection<E>)`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) foi adicionado no Java 10 e cria uma cópia imutável de uma dada lista. Se a lista dada for modificada futuramente, a cópia não será alterada.

Em versões mais antigas do Java, eu usava isso (neste caso, Java 7):

```
    public List<AlgumaCoisa> getAlgumaLista() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(algumaLista));
    }
```

De toda forma, a lista interna **nunca** é exposta diretamente para qualquer outra classe que quiser acessá-la. Isso garante o encapsulamento. Se alguma classe externa tiver interesse em modificar o conteúdo dessa lista de uma instância `x`, deverá utilizar algum dos métodos expostos por `x`, o que justifica o fato da lista retornada ser imutável.

Também justifica-se ser uma cópia porque alterações subsequentes por meio do método `adicionarItem` não devem misteriosamente se refletir em listas que embora tenham sido obtidas anteriormente a partir da instância `x`, estejam em códigos que não mais tem interesse em `x` propriamente dito.

E mesmo que uma cópia seja retornada, qualquer tentativa de modificar essa cópia diretamente é no mínimo um *code smell* ou um chamariz para bugs. Logo, mesmo sendo uma cópia, ela ainda assim tem que ser imutável.

Usar `Iterator` diretamente é difícil. O `Iterator` tem limitações de não poder ser iterado mais de uma vez (a menos que copiem-se todos os itens numa lista, mas aí seria mais fácil já dar essa lista previamente construída) e também tem  limitação de não poder determinar o tamanho da lista. Além disso, o `Iterator` é algo bastante ultrapassado, pois agora existe o `Stream`.

Existem alguns cenários onde faz sentido retornar-se um `Stream` ao invés de uma lista. Um exemplo, é quando está se percorrendo os registros de um banco de dados ou de um arquivo linha a linha. Nesse caso, faz-se isso:

```
public Stream<AlgumaCoisa> {
    // Faz alguma coisa.
}
```

Mas isso só se justifica quando não é desejado que todos os itens estejam pré-preparados em memória por questão de desempenho ou de economia de memória. Caso não seja esse o caso, retorna-se a lista.

Por fim, ainda pode se ter a preocupação de que o getter pode ficar pesado de ser executado, pois sempre que é chamado, uma nova cópia da lista será feita mesmo se for idêntica a cópia produzida na chamada anterior ao método. Então, pode-se fazer isso:

```
public class SuaClasse {

    // Embora AlgumaCoisa seja imutável, a lista em si é mutável.
    private List<AlgumaCoisa> algumaLista;
    private List<AlgumaCoisa> algumaListaImutavel;

    public SuaClasse() {
        // ...
    }

    public List<AlgumaCoisa> getAlgumaLista() {
        if (algumaListaImutavel == null) algumaListaImutavel = List.copyOf(algumaLista);
        return algumaListaImutavel;
    }

    public void adicionarItem(AlgumaCoisa adicionando) {
        this.algumaListaImutavel = null;
        this.algumaLista.add(adicionando);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu costumo fazer `return new ArrayList<>(algumaLista);` para criar a cópia, porque não vejo a obrigação da lista ser "exatamente" imutável, mas posso estar errado. E pensando aqui, alguns _iterators_ permitem remoção de elementos da lista, esse também é um ponto contra usar _iterators_.

Comment: _"E mesmo que uma cópia seja retornada, qualquer tentativa de modificar essa cópia diretamente é no mínimo um code smell ou um chamariz para bugs. Logo, mesmo sendo uma cópia, ela ainda assim tem que ser imutável."_ Agora vi isso. Pode elaborar? Por que um code smell ou chamariz para bugs? Porque deixa de refletir exatamente o conteúdo do campo original naquele momento?

Comment: @Piovezan Por quê normalmente, quando isso acontece, trata-se de uma tentativa de modificar a lista original, tentando violar o encapsulamento (e mesmo que isso não dê certo, continua sendo um problema). Não que necessariamente seja isso, mas muitas vezes é. Além disso, há uma questão semântica, pois muitas vezes essa lista representa uma parte do estado de um objeto no momento que o getter foi chamado. Tentar alterá-la diretamente significa no mínimo que há alguma outra semântica envolvida (e provavelmente uma incerta e mal-definida). [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Além disso, confiar-se no fato de que a lista retornada é mutável significa confiar-se em um detalhe de implementação de uma outra classe que não está formalmente definido por meio da assinatura de seus métodos, o que é algo que tende a produzir código frágil (ou seja, propenso a quebrar frente a mudanças internas em outras classes).

Comment: Enfim, raramente é correto modificar-se diretamente a lista retornada, mesmo que isso não altere a original. Se alguém estiver tentando fazer isso, provavelmente vai estar fazendo besteira, e assim, é melhor barrar isso logo, pois é melhor tomar uma exceção logo do que ter que quebrar a cabeça, perder tempo e ter aborrecimentos depois com *debugging*.